# vmware_tag_manager, list to string trouble

Tags: list, ansible, tags

Playbook below seems to be having trouble running thru the list of VM names..

error is as follows:

> (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire
> value to ensure it does not change.
> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find the managed object for [

then spits out the list separated with \name\

what am I doing wrong here?

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
   - name: vcenter_hostname
     prompt: Please provide the vcenter server hostname.
     private: no
   - name: vcenter_username
     prompt: Please provide the vcenter server username.
     private: no
   - name: vcenter_password
     prompt: Please provide the password for the username.
     unsafe: yes
     private: yes
  vars:
   vm_name: "{{lookup('file', '/etc/ansible/lists/lab_common_backup.txt')}}"

  tasks:
  - name: vm_tag_add
    vmware_tag_manager:
     hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
     username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
     password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
     validate_certs: no
     tag_names:
       - 'Labs: Common Backup'
     object_name: "{{ vm_name }}"
     object_type: VirtualMachine
     state: remove
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using .split(), the default delimiter for split is a space..

```
 object_name: "{{ vm_name.split() }}"
```